# Cannot add foreign key constraint using code that has previously worked

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

```
mysql> describe location;

+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| locX  | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locY  | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name  | varchar(90)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table user( 
id INT,
locationID INT,
ageRange varChar(10) NOT NULL,
gender enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
safeSleep enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
famViol enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
traveller enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
family enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
couples enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
mentEmot enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
parole enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
disabled enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
veteran enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
asylum enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
pets enum('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
INDEX par_ind (locationID),
CONSTRAINT fk_locat FOREIGN KEY (locationID)
REFERENCES location(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The table I am trying to create a foreign key to is shown at the top. Why am I getting an error message? I've used this same method making foreign keys before however this one does not work using the same code. I am teaching myself SQL so do not have a lot of experience. Thank you

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: You have to make sure that both the foreign key and referenced key have the same definition (both need to be `int(10)`) in both tables.